# How do I set manage the path of CelebA dataset on my computer to let pytorch work with it?

Tags: debugging, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

Since the limitation of Google Drive, I can't download CelebA using this code:

```
torchvision.datasets.CelebA(root='E:/BaiduNetdiskDownload', download=True, transform=transform, target_type=target_type)
```

So I downloaded the dataset to my computer. There are some zip files and 7z files in it, and I don't know whether I should unzip them, of which ones of them I should unzip. I don't want to stuck at such a low-level problem, so can anyone tell me how should I manage the downloaded CelebA?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Download the dataset, unzip the `img_align_celeba.zip`, and put other files as shown in the image. Put all about files in a folder called `celeba`, and when using the dataset with `torchvision.datasets.CelebA`, root will be the parent directory of `celeba`.